# Passing a new property called processRequest = "Accept" to sequelize json object throws error

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, axios, sequelize.js

I would like to send a new property called `processRequest = "Accept"`  to sequelize json object as below, this property need to be available in every request record. I have tried as below getting undefined and axios error.  How can we achieve that here .

```
app.get('/service/requestlist', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const requests = await RequestModel.findAll({});
    let myRequest = requests.toJSON();
    myRequest.processRequest = "Accept";
    res.status(200).json({ requests});
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

//Sample data format below where I wish to get res.data.requests in client side.

```
const data = [ 
    {
    "id" : 1,
    "photo":"images/fit2.png",
    "name" : "Test Round1",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "mobile": "34232232",
     processRequest: "Accept"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "photo":"images/fit2.png",
        "name" : "Ding Dong",
        "email" : "ding@test.com",
        "mobile": "23123110",
        processRequest: "Accept"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to add a new property using via `setDataValue('name', "value")` in the sequelize requests helped me to resolve the problem.

```
app.get('/service/requestlist', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const requests = await RequestModel.findAll({});
    requests.map(req => {
      req.setDataValue("processRequest", "Accept");
      return req;
  })
    res.status(200).json({ requests });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```